# Apply Different color for past events in Sharepoint 2013 Calendar Month and Week View

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have a scenario where i want to show all past events in different colors.
I looked if microsoft had used any different class names to differentiate between past,present and future events, but unfortunately not.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the requirement correctly. This is possible through overlay calendar view.

1. **Create a calculated column** e.g. Past Event with the formula `=[Start Time]<TODAY()`. Make sure that return type is Yes/No.

[image]

2. **Create a Calendar View** (In my case it is called 'PastEvents-Cal' and ensure Filter is set to 'Yes'

[image]

3. Create **an Overlay Calendar**. You will be able to select the Calendar View you have created.  Good tutorial about overlay calendar [here](http://www.degdigital.com/insights/four-easy-steps-to-customized-color-code-calendars-in-sharepoint/) and [here](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/20/customize-the-sharepoint-calendar-colors/)
   [image]

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually my requirement is to display events(past,present,future) events in alternative colors for example blue and green. Upto this I have implemented and all events are showing in alternate colors. Now I want to show past events in lighter shades of blue/green color.

Comment: Did you try what I have suggested?

Comment: Yes I have tried. It displays past events two times. One from the current view and another from the PastEvents view. Event then there are only few colors available in overlay. The requirement is to have lighter shades of present event color.

Comment: Please look at the tutorial links provided 1) two events, you need to create an empty filter view - details is provided in the step 3 tutorial 1, 2) second tutorial providing details about the colors.